# Setup One to Many without Foreign Key Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio, entity-relationship

I have the following design.
[image]
As we can see from this image, an Episode will have multiple EpisodePatients, and each of these EpisodePatients, will point to one Episode.

Here are my two models corresponding to the tables.

```
public class EpisodeModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual EpisodePatientModel EpisodePatient { get; set; }
}
public class EpisodePatientModel
{
    public int EpisodePatientID { get; set; }
    public virtual EpisodeModel Episode { get; set; }
}
```

How do I setup the One to Many relationship between `EpisodeModel` and `EpisodePatientModel`?

Since `EpisodeModel` does not contain a foreign key to EpisodePatient, I cannot do the following.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EpisodeModel>().HasRequired(r => r.EpisodePatient).WithMany().HasForeignKey() //No foreign key
```

I have tried this.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EpisodeModel>().HasRequired(r => r.EpisodePatient);
```

But with this approach, the EpisodeModel is not Lazy loaded when loading all EpisodePatientModels form the DB

Comment: I'm wondering how many questions are you planning to post on this issue. Apparently your model is wrong. `one-to-many` means one of the sides must have a **collection**, not a single reference.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your model does not reflect what you say. If there is *one-to-many* relationship between `EpisodeModel` and `EpisodePatientModel` you must have collection of `EpisodePatientModel`. And you are missing *foreign key* property at `EpisodePatientModel`:

```
public class EpisodeModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EpisodePatientModel> EpisodePatients { get; set; } // Must be collection
}

public class EpisodePatientModel
{
    public int EpisodePatientID { get; set; }
    public int EpisodeID { get; set; } // Foreign key to Episode
    public virtual EpisodeModel Episode { get; set; }
}
```

Then after your models are correct, mappings with Fluent API is easy to understand, map them as you say: one `EpisodeModel` can have *many* `EpisodePatientModel`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EpisodeModel>()
    .HasMany(r => r.EpisodePatients)
    .WithRequired(m => m.Episode)
    .HasForeignKey(m => m.EpisodeID);
```

Or you can map reverse of this. Adding one of these two is enough:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EpisodePatientModel>()
    .HasRequired(r => r.Episode)
    .WithMany(m => m.Episode)
    .HasForeignKey(m => m.EpisodeID);
```

Comment: Although there is currently a One to Many relatioship with the data in the DB, in my code, I am trying to "trick" EF to think that there is a one to one relationship between the data. I am selecting all EpisodePatient records from the table, joined with the Episode Table, so the data returned will act as if there is a One to one relationship. I cannot declare a ICollection<EpisodePatientModel> on the EpisodeModel, since I want to   be able to update the single entity related to the EpisodeModel through it, like this, for instance, episodeModel.EpisodePatient = "". Hope this makes sense

Comment: @monstertjie_za, first of all it not a good choice. Secondly, to map *one-to-one* relationship you need to set `modelBuilder.Entity<EpisodeModel>().HasOptional(r => r.EpisodePatient).WithRequired(m => m.Episode);`. Specifing *foreign key* is not required, since *one-to-one* relationships are mapped through their primary keys. But I am not sure if it works.

Comment: Nope, this did not work. I will have to restructure the way it currently works

Comment: Does this with with EF6 or 7? I'm trying it now, but unfortunately, neither 6 nor 7 have the .WithMany nor the HasRequired, maybe I'm missing something? How can this be done with current EF?

Answer (score 2):

I understood that you need to have a foreign key in the EpisodePatient table that refers to the Episode table Id, so I think you can solve it like this:

```
public class EpisodeModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<EpisodePatientModel> EpisodePatients { get; set; }
}

public class EpisodePatientModel
{
    public int EpisodePatientID { get; set; }
    public int EpisodeID { get; set; }
    public virtual EpisodeModel Episode { get; set; }
}
```

And then, your configuration should go like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EpisodePatientModel>().HasRequired(r => r.Episode).WithMany(e => e.EpisodePatients).HasForeignKey(r => r.EpisodeID);
```